# Android - lazy loading of ListView with web-SQL results using JSON and http?

Tags: android, sql, json

I'm currently working on an app which has to query a web SQL db, and show the results in a ListView, and I would really appreciate some input as to what is the best way to do that.

I would like the results to be shown as quickly as possible, so if I can somehow show the first result immediately while still loading the rest that would be great.

Reading on the subject, it seems the best way to send the data (which includes a small image) is using a JSON object (or array).

The ideas I had so far:
* Http requests with index of last result - downside is that the server will run the same query over and over again and just send me a few results at a time.
* Open a socket between device and server until user leaves the results view - downside is excessive use of network resource.

Do they sound OK?
Is there something else I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> The ideas I had so far: * Http requests with index of last result -
>   downside is that the server will run the same query over and over
>   again and just send me a few results at a time. *

=> This is the standard idea but I would say sending request and fetching data depends on the particular requirement, like you should use **Service** concept if you would want to show first set of result and at the same make a call for another sets in *background*.

So whenever service gets another sets of data, it sends a message to your activity with the received new data set and your activity will update the UI with the available new data.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'service concept'? Do you mean running a background thread to load further results?

Comment: @Talor yes background Service which will fetch data in background and will be updating UI as and when new data is arrived.